# how to make default page home.php instead of index.html and index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have website http://mywebsite.com If I hit this URL it take index.php and index.html as default page. How can I make home.php as default page.
I have tried this but not working by placing following code inside .htaccess file of public_html

```
DirectoryIndex home.php index.html index.php
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You just need `home.php` in your `DirectoryIndex` to make it works. Remember that this is using in .htaccess file of your root project:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Comment: It applies to all sub folders. I want to apply only to the root folder only.

Comment: NB: This code will apply for all your sub folders. Use the below code instead of 'DirectoryIndex' . >>>>>>>>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /yourfile.html [L]

Answer (score 13):

You need `AllowOverride +Indexes` in your `httpd.conf` to be able to use `DirectoryIndex` in `.htaccess`.

Barring that, the absolutely easiest way to redirect (without the root access to Apache config and modules) is putting this as `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=home.php">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But which way is better? Which one is faster? Isn't it better for the user, to go directly to the home.html instead of being redirected from one url to another?

Comment: @PrzemysławNiemiec Yes, it is. The second solution is the work-around for when you have no control of Apache, as written in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

DirectoryIndex directive applies to all subfolders, if you want set  diffrent files for each directories, you can use mod-rewrite.

To set **/file.html** as root directory handler,  you can use this at the top of your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /file.html [L]
```

To set a diffrent file as index for a subfolder, use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/$ /myfile.html [L]
```

Answer (score -2):

Just try to rewrite `/index.html` and `/index.php` into `/home.php`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.(html|php)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /home.php
```