# Set custom default page for root directory only (not for subdirectories)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I used the solution given on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15779198/4932070) for this.

```
        DirectoryIndex home.php
```

but it applies to root directory and its subdirectories. However, I need a solution that set default page for only root directory, not for the subfolders. I looked around a lot, but couldn't find one.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See this answer. It's on your link as well..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779198/how-to-make-default-page-home-php-instead-of-index-html-and-index-php#answer-15779251

Comment: @Refilon, I cannot use this solution, as I want open a custom page when a user access my website. He/she has to select an option on this page and after that, he/she will be redirected to Index page. However, this code is affecting subfolders as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need a solution that set default page for only root directory, not for the subfolders

You can do this using a rewrite rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ home.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, can `DirectoryIndex home.php` be modified in some way to solve this problem?

Comment: `DirectoryIndex` cannot be conditional. Better to set `DirectoryIndex` to some generic handler like `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` and use this rule for document root directory.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again for the solution, it is working correct.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava Can you please explain what is this part exactly doing: ^/?$