# display only the domain name instead of the full address path when I enter my webpage

Tags: url

How can I manage to display only the domain name instead of the full address path when I enter my webpage?

For example, when I search 'name.com', I want the search bar shows only 'myname.com' instead of 'www.name.com/page.html'.

my index.php entrance:

```
<?php
    header( 'Location: http://www.xxxxx.com/xxxx.html' ) ;
?>
```

and I have a corresponding 'xxx.html' file.

I've tried adding the following lines to .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://name.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

.

it successfully hiding 'www' prefix, however, I also want to hide '/xxxx.html' part.
How to do that?

Comment: is this question just about homepage or entire website?

Comment: just the homepage is fine. I could not figure it out @Ali Sheikhpour

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the **default document** in server settings. Server will serach and find the default document and servs it as hompage of http://www.example.com/

In a windows server you can set default document using IIS manager > Default documents or directly by this code in `web.config` file :

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="home.html" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

in a linux server , you should first edit `.htaccess` file and define the home file:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

and then to hide the home file from address bar you need uisng rewrite rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home.php?/$1 [L]
```

for more details in linux server please refer to tihs [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779198/how-to-make-default-page-home-php-instead-of-index-html-and-index-php) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url) and for windows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/defaultdocument/).

If you are using a shared hosting company and have access to control panel, you can set default documents usually in in **websites** section.

Comment: I've tried adding these lines to .htaccess file. but it only hides 'www' prefix. It now displays 'xxxxx.com/xxx.html'.  However, I am trying to hide the actual .html path as well, and let search bar only displays 'xxxxx.com' .

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xxxxx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://xxxxx.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]           ,      these are lines being added to .htaccess file.